# Call Python script from bash shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to implement a command which involves sending `POST/GET` request to a remote server and interpret `JSON` format result. Since it's quite hard to parse JSON via `bash`, I decide to write python script first and call it within the shell script.

My shell script now looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  submit-job)
    python3 src/submit-job.py
    ;;
  lists-job)
    python3 src/lists-job.py
    ;;
  ....and so on
esac
```

I hope my users can use this command as following.

```
Job submit-job argument1 argument2...
Job lists-job
...and so on
```

Basically. I have only 1 Python class file called `Job.py` including multiple functions like `submit-job` and `lists-job`. 
However, in order to separate different functions to a different command argument, I have to create seperate python files to trigger it. (Like `submit-job.py` and `lists-job.py`).

For example. **submit-job.py**

```
from Job import Job

j = Job()
j.submit_job()
```

**lists-job.py**

```
from Job import Job

j = Job()
j.lists_job()
```

As you can see, they are quite similar. Is there a better way or best practice to achieve what I want?

Comment: `python job-tools.py submit`, and then have your Python script check its command-line arguments. (Even better, have distutils/setuptools create an executable wrapper, then it's just `job-tools submit`, no needing to explicitly call the python interpreter).

Comment: A common technique is to have a single file with multiple links, and then have the program examine $0.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...or, in the Python sense, examine `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look on distutils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do the if/else in Python?

```
import sys
from Job import Job

j = Job()
arg = sys.argv[1]
if arg == 'submit-job':
    j.submit_job()
elif ...
    ...
```

Now you can call this from within the bash script, passing the argument, or even remove the bash script already and invoke the Python script directly from the command line.

Comment: This is a good approach I have not thought about it. Thanks!